# apt-get requests installation media after installing Debian 7

Tags: linux, debian

I installed Debian to VMware Fusion 6 on OS X via the first ISO from [Debian's image archive](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/7.3.0/i386/iso-dvd/).

Now, when I try to run `apt-get` under certain conditions, i.e. `apt-get install make`,  I get the following error:

```
Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Debian GNU/Linux 7.3.0 _Wheezy_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20131215-03:40'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter
```

I have no idea why it would be prompting me for physical media of any sort -- any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Easy to fix. Edit this file `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` then comment out `#deb cdrom:`

Here's my wheezy sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 CD Binary-1 20130$

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 CD Binary-1 20130$

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to (re)build the apt CD/DVD package index.

Become root and remount the iso image at /media/cdrom
than run  'apt-cdrom add'